# Generate Value > Save and Return Generated Value on Django REST Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have the following code, it works but half way. What i want to be able to do is

save (studentID, tutorID, sessionID) on the database.

**Pseudo Code**

```
GENREATE SESSION_ID

SAVE (SESSION_ID, STUDENTID, TUTORID)

RETURN SESSION_ID AS RESPONSE
```

Views.py

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def startCall(request, studentID, tutorID):

if request.method == 'POST':

    API_KEY = 'APIKEY'
    API_SECRET = 'API_SECRET'
    OTSDK = OpenTokSDK.OpenTokSDK(API_KEY,API_SECRET)
    session_id = OTSDK.create_session().session_id

    response = {}
    response['session_id'] = str(session_id)
    return Response(response)
```

serializers.py

```
class startCallSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

class Meta:
    model = call
    fields = ('tutor', 'billed', 'billed_status',
              'tutor_status', 'sid', 'started', 'finished')
```

Comment: you need to describe what is working properly and what isn't working properly along with any relevant code

Comment: I need is to save session_id on sid field and then show it to the user. but i dont want to pass sid parameter on the POST request. any idea?

Comment: I get that. But you said half of the code is working.  You need to describe what half is working and what half is not working and describe the expected behavior.  can you do that?

Comment: @skzryzg this a better example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23328647/pre-save-signal-to-pass-a-value-to-a-django-rest-serializer i made a new question more clear. thanks if you could help :)